# PowerShell script to extract .xls file from specific Outlook folder

Tags: excel, powershell, outlook, powershell-2.0, etl

I want to extract and save an .xls file from an email I receive daily. I have a rule set up which saves the email in an Outlook mailbox, within a specific subfolder of the Inbox.

The Outlook folder structure looks like this:

```
-> Inbox

--> Data (subfolder of "Inbox")

---> ToExtract (subfolder of "Data")
```

I need to extract the .xls file from the "ToExtract" folder.

[I found a script](http://theolddogscriptingblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/save-and-open-outlook-attachments-using-powershell/) that does most of the work for me, but it requires the user to supervise the script and manually select which Outlook folder to search. I need to change the script so it just points to the "ToExtract" subfolder.

The code is below. It works fine, but I need to modify the `pickfolder()` part.

```
#file path
$filepath = “c:\test\”


#set outlook to open
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)


#you'll get a popup in outlook at this point where you pick the folder you want to scan
$f = $n.pickfolder()

#date string to search for in attachment name
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd


#now loop through them and grab the attachments
$f.Items | foreach {
    $_.attachments | foreach {
    Write-Host $_.filename
    $a = $_.filename
    If ($a.Contains($date)) {
    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $a))
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
$Account = $n.Folders | ? { $_.Name -eq 'username@domain.com' };
$Inbox = $Account.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'Inbox' };
$f = $Inbox.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'ToExtract' };
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but as mentioned in the original post, `ToExtract` is a subfolder within a subfolder of `Inbox`

Answer (score -1):

```
$MailboxName = "MAILBOX"
$Subject = "EMAIL SUBJECT"
$ProcessedFolderPath = "/Inbox/Processed"
$downloadDirectory = "c:\temp"

Function FindTargetFolder($FolderPath){
    $tfTargetidRoot = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$MailboxName)
    $tfTargetFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$tfTargetidRoot)
    $pfArray = $FolderPath.Split("/")
    for ($lint = 1; $lint -lt $pfArray.Length; $lint++) {
        $pfArray[$lint]
        $fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1)
        $SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+isEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$pfArray[$lint])
                $findFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($tfTargetFolder.Id,$SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView)
        if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -gt 0){
            foreach($folder in $findFolderResults.Folders){
                $tfTargetFolder = $folder               
            }
        }
        else{
            "Error Folder Not Found"
            $tfTargetFolder = $null
            break
        }   
    }
    $Global:findFolder = $tfTargetFolder
}

$dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1)


$windowsIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$sidbind = "LDAP://<SID=" + $windowsIdentity.user.Value.ToString() + ">"
$aceuser = [ADSI]$sidbind

$service.AutodiscoverUrl($aceuser.mail.ToString())

FindTargetFolder($ProcessedFolderPath)

$folderid = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
$InboxFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
$Sfir = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::IsRead, $false)
$Sfsub = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject, $Subject)
$Sfha = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::HasAttachments, $true)
$sfCollection = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And);
$sfCollection.add($Sfir)
$sfCollection.add($Sfsub)
$sfCollection.add($Sfha)
$view = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(2000)
$frFolderResult = $InboxFolder.FindItems($sfCollection,$view)
foreach ($miMailItems in $frFolderResult.Items){
    $miMailItems.Subject
    $miMailItems.Load()
    foreach($attach in $miMailItems.Attachments){
    $attach.Load()
        $fiFile = new-object System.IO.FileStream(($downloadDirectory + “\” + $attach.Name.ToString()), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $fiFile.Write($attach.Content, 0, $attach.Content.Length)
        $fiFile.Close()
        write-host "Downloaded Attachment : " + (($downloadDirectory + “\” + $attach.Name.ToString()))
    }
    $miMailItems.isread = $true
    $miMailItems.Update([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConflictResolutionMode]::AlwaysOverwrite)
    [VOID]$miMailItems.Move($Global:findFolder.Id)
}
```

From https://gist.github.com/bleep-io/5151579