# Powershell script to extract and rename .xls from outlook

Tags: excel, email, outlook, powershell-2.0, extract

I want to extract an .xls file from an e-mail in Outlook, rename it and save it to a folder. I have found some scripts, but non of them is fully implemented after my needs.

**Post updated.**

I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587841/powershell-script-to-extract-xls-file-from-specific-outlook-folder), but it does not rename, could this code be amended to fulfill my requirements?

```
#file path
$filepath = “c:\test”


#set outlook to open
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)


#you'll get a popup in outlook at this point where you pick the folder you want to scan
$Account = $n.Folders | ? { $_.Name -eq 'name@domain.com' };
$Inbox = $Account.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'Inbox' };
$f = $Inbox.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'subfolder' };

#string to search for in attachment name
$file = '.xlsx'


#now loop through them and grab the attachments
$f.Items | foreach {
    $_.attachments | foreach {
    Write-Host $_.filename
    $a = $_.filename
    $b = 'Rename ' + $a
    If ($a.Contains($file)) {

    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $b))
      }
  }

}
```

**Post updated.**

> This script works on my own mailbox. I though have an Public Folder
>   added to my Outlook, is it possible to access a folder inside the the
>   Public Folder by tweaking this script?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you want the rename but here is a `counter++` example:
add a new variable before `foreach` statement:

```
$counter=0
```

then in the foreach do next to increase by 1

```
 $counter++
```

in the end rename the extracted files like this

```
$_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath "file$counter.xlsx"))
```

Better is to give an example with 2 real filenames and tell how do you expect the output